# Check if VB.net dataset table exists

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, dataset

I have the following code to check if my table exists before proceeding

```
        If ds.Tables(3).Rows.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Nothing!!!!")
        Else
            DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(3)
```

The trouble is I keep getting the error "Cannot find table 3."

How in VB can I check if the table exists, rather than my application erroring I just want it to do nothing if the table doesn't exist.

I have also tried

```
If ds is nothing
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't know if the `DataSet` is initialized:

```
If ds IsNot Nothing Then
    ' ... '
End If
```

If you don't know if it contains **four** tables(zero based indices):

```
If ds.Tables.Count >= 4 Then
        ' ... '
End If
```

So the final super safe version is:

```
If ds IsNot Nothing AndAlso ds.Tables.Count >= 4 Then
    Dim table As DataTable = ds.Tables(3)
End If
```

If you now also want to know if that table contains rows:

```
Dim isEmpty As Boolean = table.Rows.Count = 0
```

Answer (score 5):

See if the dataset contains the table if you are unsure if it exists:

```
If mdsMyDataSet1.Tables.Contains("Table3") = True Then
   'Do Something with it
End If
```